# Javascript check for Max/Min/Average number from a record set

Tags: javascript

```
function lab09unknownLoopCountPart2() {

//Constants
var ONE_HUNDRED = 100;
var ZERO = 0;

//Variables
var employeeHourlyWage;
var hourlyMaximum = ZERO;
var hourlyMinimum = ZERO;
var totalHourlyWage = ZERO;
var records;
var counter = ZERO;
var average;

records = openEmployeePayrollRecords();

while (records.readNextRecord()) {
   employeeHourlyWage  = records.getEmployeeHourlyWage();
   totalHourlyWage += employeeHourlyWage;
   counter++;
   average = totalHourlyWage / counter;

   if (employeeHourlyWage < ONE_HUNDRED) {
       hourlyMaximum = employeeHourlyWage;
   }
   if (employeeHourlyWage < ONE_HUNDRED) {
       hourlyMinimum = employeeHourlyWage;
   }
}
document.write("Average Hourly Wage: " + average + "<br />");
document.write("Maximum Hourly Wage: "  + hourlyMaximum + "<br />");
document.write("Minimum Hourly Wage: " + hourlyMinimum + "<br />");
```

}

The record set is simply numbers from 15 - 30. I have to sort through them and find the Maximum, Minimum and Average.

I know that my two IF statements are incorrect and I'm wondering how to check this, **without** using Math.min and Math.max.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   var hourlyMinimum = -1;
   var hourlyMaximum = -1;

   if (hourlyMaximum === -1 || employeeHourlyWage > hourlyMaximum ) {
       hourlyMaximum = employeeHourlyWage;
   }
   if (hourlyMinimum === -1 || employeeHourlyWage < hourlyMinimum ) {
       hourlyMinimum = employeeHourlyWage;
   }
```

Assuming wages cannot be negative.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (employeeHourlyWage > hourlyMaximum)
    hourlyMaximum = employeeHourlyWage;
if (employeeHourlyWage < hourlyMinimum)
    hourlyMinimum = employeeHourlyWage;
```

Also you could move average calculation outside of the loop cuz it's value used only outside.

By the way, what's the point of using those ZERO and ONE_HUNDRED constants - they are not anyhow semantical.

Comment: That's simply the way my instructor has us declaring constants, should I not declare them? I'm a bit confused by what you mean.

Comment: The point of declaring constants is to eliminate strange values from code and to show real meaning of those values - it makes understanding the code easier. You replaced 0 with ZERO and 100 with ONE_HUNDRED which makes no difference in understanding what are those values for. You could use 0 instead of ZERO and something like MAX_POSSIBLE_HOURLY_WAGE instead of HUNDRED.

Answer (score 0):

For your two "if conditions" you are checking whether the new value for wage is greater than the maximum or minimum.

Where `hourlyMaximum` gives the maximum value for each EmployeeHourlyWage in the EmployeePayrollRecords set.

and

`hourlyMinimum` gives the minimum value for each EmployeeHourlyWage in the EmployeePayrollRecords set.

So for each iteration in the while loop you need to reassign the value of the wage with in the if block.

If the current wage acquired from records is greater than the current maximum then assign it otherwise don't. A similar process for the minimum.

The current "if blocks" just reassigns the value of the hourly minimum and maximum wages once it is lower than 100 (ONE_HUNDRED)

To prove to yourself that you are indeed getting the correct values ,try outputting them by code and by hand.